# What is the best HTTP library for Java in terms of performance and reliability?

Tags: java, http

I want to make HTTP requests to Solr index to get requested documents.
What is the best (both fast and reliable) HTTP client library in Java? (Is there anything similar to Ruby's typhoeus)?

Comment: Can't really answer this without doing a lot of empirical testing... I like Apache Commons HttpClient; it's been good enough for my needs.

Comment: Here's a benchmark ready to be performed. Maybe you can draw your own conclussions: http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/HttpClient3vsHttpClient4vsHttpCore

Answer (score 5):

Apache HttpComponents (former The Commons HttpClient) http://hc.apache.org/ is a de facto standard in Java world. Solr client library is using it as well: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

Answer (score 2):

HttpUrlConnection is pretty damn fast these days.